# So Many Commits to (no branch)

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

By mistake I have made many days of work's commits to no where. When I checked the current branch git replied me with a (no branch).

I in fact was under the impression that I was committing to a new branch (other than the master), and everything is going fine. Now when I traverse back and check for the branch of even a very old commit (about a month back) still git says it is in no where (i.e. no branch).

I know that merging will help if it is only one commit. Now how am I to get all the previous commits merged with the master?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably committed on a so called "detached HEAD" (for example after `git checkout abc123ef`).

If you know the commit you committed last (i.e. the `HEAD` of your "lost" branch), you should be able to reset the branch to this commit and everything will be fine: `git branch -f some-branch cbd131ef`.

Comment: And if you don't know the last commit, you can probably find it with `git reflog`

Answer (score 3):

When you do checkout to "no branch" git says:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
>   may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.
>   Example:
>
> git checkout -b new_branch_name

Of course you could merge as much commits as you want.

To find a detached head if you lost it you can use git reflog.

Also you should remember that a detached head could be garbage collected.

Comment: Hi kan; Thanks. But I can't find the 'detached HEAD' in the reflog. What can be the reason?

Comment: You have to find your commits here. It is not named as "detached head".

Comment: I am not sure what's the state of your repo now. Is it on your latest commit? Just do "git checkout -b new_branch_name" then. After it you can switch to the master and merge the branch.